# AS3 fill container(box) with assorted MovieClips(space-fill)

Tags: actionscript-3

I am looking for a way to efficiently fill a container with different shapes adapting to eachother. I have tried adding to rows and columns ut it doesnt give the right "organic" feeling. I have also tried placing at random but theres too much empty space, and its clogging up my resources after a few thousand elements
So I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction on how I may accomplish this in AS3 adding and placing objects from library. Sizes of elements may vary, and the fill does not have to be "perfect". No animation involved, result is static

[A rough sketch below with exadurated differences in shapes(the waterbuckled paper is of little or no importance)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbxPm.jpg)

Comment: If I were solving something like this I'd go for 2D physics engine, say http://www.box2dflash.org/

Comment: Fantastic, just what I was looking for. Thank you!